# tomcat 10 with client certificate authenticiation

Tags: tomcat10

All i trying to migrate a server from tomcat9 to tomcat 10 however facing issue while enabling client authentication

Can you guide me to convert the below tomcat9 configuration in to tomcat10

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
        clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
        keystoreFile="conf/vphhgw.cloud.ffftfbinffftra.net.keystore"
keystorePass="#{{keystorePass}}#"
        truststoreFile="conf/DfTffNA-QA-Tfrfucks-Bundle-Truststoreca.jks" truststorePass="#{{keystorePass}}#" truststoreType="JKS" />
```